# Lora sx1278 implementation by Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, lora, lorawan

I'm implementing a Lora network, with two SX1278 modules and Arduino Uno. Lora is based on three classes. A , B and C, The question is : for change For example A to B, what should exactly change in communication?
and How does it change the beacon?. I clearly mean, Does it need to send a particular and standard message to the receiver ? Or Will just communicating in scheduled time change the class or changing some control bits is needed?

Comment: Arduino is C++, not C

Comment: Just use a LoRaWAN stack. Implementing your own is stupid and a waste of time

Comment: what is LoraWAN stack?! whould you please explain it for me?

Comment: is this a device or what?

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/mcci-lorawan-lmic-library/

Answer (score 1):

about your question
Lora-wan(communication protocol and network architecture that sits on top of the Lora physical layer) is based on the classes not Lora.

the different between them is:
Lora : is a wireless modulation technique derived from Chirp Spread Spectrum (CSS) technology.
Lora-wan :  is a Media Access Control (MAC) layer protocol built on top of Lora modulation(((((((((Software Layer))))))).
[image]

so what the programmer should know from that?
when you buy any Lora module you should read about the device details if it support the Lora-wan or not?

if your devices support Lora-wan then you can implement the three classes you mention (A,B,C) and those classes created to reduce the power consumption and communication technique ( how is that??) let's see these three type and what can do for us:-

1- class A : simply when you build network contain many nodes and gateway the nodes will send to the gateway and after send will change from send(mode) to receive(listing)mode for responding from the gateway and as you can see the listing in two different time but if node receive from first time it will cancel the second time.((class B and C should support Class A))

[image]

2- class B(beacon) : it's addition of class A but take more receive mode at scheduled times
[image]

3- class C(ontinuous) : addition to Class A the node after send it will listing the whole time for responding class C take more power due to the continuous listing.
[image]

as you can see both class B,C need to support class A.

for more info see:
https://lora.readthedocs.io/en/latest/